# Error copying profile to all network accounts when nothing has changed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

When visiting my edit profile page from stackoverflow and click 'Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts' without making any changes I receive the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   temporary error updating your profile -- please try again!

Reproduced multiple times in

- Chrome 15.0.874.120 m
- FireFox 8.0

After changed - even a single character - It works as expected.

I think it should just do nothing on the back-ground and say it was succesfull - or display an notice that you havn't made any changes.

Comment: Didn't happen to me. Probably was temporary glitch.

Comment: I have tried this multiple times - and was able to reproduce this every time. Even right now whilst writing this comment.

Comment: Have you tried with other browser? After changing something?

Comment: Updated my original post.

Comment: Hmm.. so guess moderator/developer will have to look into the error logs and see what happened.

Comment: Repeatedly reproduced in Chrome ∞. It fails unless I've made a change to the form information before submitting. If I save a change to the current site, then go back and try to copy these changes to the other sites without making new changes, it will fail.

Comment: This issue also occurs if you save a profile edit on for example stackoverflow and then go back to the page to copy it to all your other network accounts.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you just need to not be so fast.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184911/136973