# Copy profile to other accounts is not working for me

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-copying

When I hit the button that says "Copy profile to all stack exchange network accounts"

I get the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> temporary error updating your profile -- please try again!

I'm logged in via Facebook. If there's anything more I can help with "just let met know".

Comment: I'd finish your sentence before you submit your question...

Comment: "... be happy to transfer you $50 via PayPal?" I'm in!

Comment: Seriously though, can you try again? This has happened to me before, and I managed to fix it by retrying a few minutes later.

Comment: Finished the sentence and.. I've tried again. I still get the error but it seems to have worked anyway, on all of the stack exchange network sites my accounts have synched.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113337/error-copying-profile-to-all-network-accounts-when-nothing-has-changed

Comment: Everything seems to work fine with my yahoo account...

Answer (score 1):

There was a database deadlock caused by a large accounts table update lock and your trying to get get the list of sites to copy to at the same time (rare, but it happens), we see a few a week under varying circumstances.

You only needed to try again :)  I've pushed the button for you, all is well, copied, synced, etc.