# Bug when clicking "Save and Copy Profile..." fast

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

At the moment, you get an error message when you try to update your profile fast.

Steps to reproduce

- Go to your profile page in StackOverflow (or another SE site)
- Press "edit" to edit the profile
- Immediately press "Save and Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts"

[image]
How this happened to me:

I wanted to push my SO info to other SE sites.

**Possible fix:**

- Wait for the page to be ready before showing the button
- Display an appropriate message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an intentional security measure.

Comment: Sounds like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113337/152859) is also by design then, the OP there most likely clicked too fast.